# Windows 10 POS Touchscreen Scrolling, How?

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

We've just acquired an OKPOS Optimus Nova, Windows 10, POS.

We have a problem with the touchscreen. You are only able to scroll by touching the sidebar of an app. Not, as you would expect, by touching any part of the screen whilst swiping your finger up or down such as with your phone or tablet.

Is there universal way to fix this in Windows 10 as there doesn't seem to be much support from OKPOS.

Are there any universal PCAP drivers or applications that may help?

Edit:  the screen supports 10 point multitouch.It is listed as a PCAP touch display.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the screen actually support multitouch control? Sounds like this is just not possible.

Comment: Yes 10 point multitouch.

Comment: It claims to be 10 point capacitive.   .. but it also claims that an intel i3 is a "high performance" processor.

Comment: i3 probably could be considered high performance for a POS system. Although I get your point.